# android layouts and exporting a jar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, jar

The problem is this:

I have an android layout, let's call it ad.xml. Ad.xml will be included in my android project, and from there eclipse generates the R.* classes.

I an another project called ad-sdk, that will be exported as a jar, and contains a class that references those R.* classes being generated in the project that contains the ad layout.

If I export the jar, it exports with compile time errors. Is there anyway that a jar can be exported that references classes from another project. It doesn't seem like there would be way, but I wanted to make sure.

Essentially, I want to be able to create multiple projects, drag in the ad.xml to each of those projects, which then results in R.* class files, and include the ad-sdk.jar in each of those projects.

Comment: Of course one way around this whole problem is to create the view programmatically in my ad-sdk, but let's assume that's not an option for now.

Comment: You should edit your question to add that point.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway that a jar can be exported that references classes from another project.

Not from the hosting project directly via `R` values.

> Essentially, I want to be able to create multiple projects, drag in the ad.xml to each of those projects, which then results in R.* class files, and include the ad-sdk.jar in each of those projects.

Pass in the `R.layout` value to the host's desired layout to the JAR via some API, and have the JAR use that layout instead of hard-wiring in `R.layout.ad`.